# Convert base class instance to derived class without type casting in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I extended a new class form a base class and added some properties.
How can I create an instance of derived class with a given base class including additional props?

This code works but casts the class type and is **not Type Safe**

##### How can I do it without type casting?

```js
// Base class is imported from a package. Not editable
class BaseClass {
  public x: number;
  public power() {
    return this.x * 2;
  }
}

export interface CustomClass extends BaseClass {
  value: number;
}

function createCustomClass(base: BaseClass, myValue: number): CustomClass {

  // it's not type safe to cast this variable
  // How to do it the right way in Typescript?
  const result: CustomClass = base as CustomClass;
  result.value = myValue;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to go `const result: CustomClass = structuredClone(base);` ?

Comment: Why not extend a class using extends?,  `class CustomClass extends BaseClass {}`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W46nAN) using `Object.assign()` meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, It seems to be the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to add properties to a target object.  The method returns the target object, and the return type for [its call signature in the TypeScript library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d3513ee5c4960467c458c5d567437194aa3e828c/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L260-L285) is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the types of the inputs.

That means your `createCustomClass()` can be implemented like this:

```
function createCustomClass(base: BaseClass, myValue: number): CustomClass {
  return Object.assign(base, { value: myValue });
}
```

The return type is `BaseClass & {value: number}`, which is structurally identical to `CustomClass` and thus the function compiles without error, and there's no [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) needed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4rQN4ChrQA4FcAjEAS2GgA8AuaAO3wFtCEAnaAXmgAYBuaAen7QAngHt80CAAtxIACbQwIAO5hhMErRIAXEkpIAvBCPFsAZiQTyI2PEVLlco5awAUASgy2cLBNvwstNDaUiQQAHQU0ABU0ABMPLYAvpgpmAgUTiza0JrarGZgwMZI+BDaogwokDAZ+bRyMPAQyKgwWDgAbkr4CDT0TKyJaWb4tMC6okHAvmD5peWV1VCuhIg0za01ADTQDMIAaj19dIzMLO40CxVVbV4+fgFBAPKEAFYIE+E1JADmtKtELt0NBuiBejR9kdwcYku5hkA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to completely exclude type casting, using your approach, but it will be safe if you'll check whether the variable `result` is valid `CustomClass` by using `type guard`(`isCustomClass` in my implementation):

```
// Base class is imported from a package. Not editable
class BaseClass {
  public x: number;
  public power() {
    return this.x * 2;
  }
}

export interface CustomClass extends BaseClass {
  value: number;
}

function isCustomClass(classToCheck: any): classToCheck is CustomClass {
  return (
    typeof classToCheck?.value === "number" && classToCheck instanceof BaseClass
  );
}

function createCustomClass(base: BaseClass, myValue: number): CustomClass {
  const result = base;
  (result as CustomClass).value = myValue;
  if (!isCustomClass(result)) {
    throw new Error("Cannot create valid `CustomClass`");
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: But type guard should not be needed because we already know that result has all the props.

Comment: @rostamiani But TS doesn't

Comment: Absolutely, bit using assign, typescript wulll know. This is the correct answer.